# Wi-Fi Direct delay

Tags: android, real-time, wifi-direct

I have to do an android app to communicate an smartphone with a computer (Java application).
I need a delay below than 50 ms at most.

Does anyone know if direct Wi-Fi Direct serves to audio systems in real-time?

Comment: You're looking for the term "latency" -- this might help you in googling for it. However, I believe that the audio latency in the android device, especially in pre-ICS versions is significantly worse. You might want to look into that as well; I remember a pretty lengthy discussion about this, concluding that earlier Android versions are not suitable for real-time audio.

Comment: Useful your comment. Thank you so much!